I get an error when I try to insert an image into a blob
I need to insert an image in the MySQL 'cover' table. The table has several columns, but the error is only in the one of type 'MediumBlob' (datafile) and in which I have to insert the image
The code I use is as follows:
image = open(fileName, 'rb').read()  # open binary file in read mode
#image = base64.b64encode(image)
#image_read = image.read()
conn, cursor = Functions.openDB(self, dbname='books')
mime = 'image/jpeg'
query = "UPDATE `cover` SET `datafile` = %s, WHERE idx = %s " % (image, idx )

try:
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
except Error as e:
    Functions.handle_error(self, message=e)
    self.container.close()

The error is

Syntax error: near 'xffxd8xffxe0x00x10JFIFx00x01x01x01x00'x00'x00x00xffxdbx00Cx00' at line 1

Whether you use the binary read-only file or encode it in base64 after reading. Obviously the in this case changes the string reported by the error.
I searched the net and all I found was practically the above code
Some suggestions are not applicable since:

I get a syntax error due, I suppose, to a wrong encode in something understandable from MySQL
They deal with strings and/or integers while my question refers to the insertion of an image in a blob.
In all the scripts in which I access the database, the syntactic construction is correct


Don't use % formatting like sql % values, use parameter substitution like (sql, values).  As described here

Also don't quote %s.

Do not add things like UPDATED -  to a title when you edit your question. Nor include edit/update markers within the question body. After an edit, your question should be as if it was asked that way from the start. Also, the problem is that you've made yourself a giant SQL injection hole, and the way the value is spliced in the string is syntactically invalid. You need to use parameters as shown in the duplicate.

Thank you for the suggestion. I entered "UPDATE" to point out to the moderators that I had made changes. I assumed that the moderator would delete that word.

That is not how you're supposed to use this site. If you edit your question and tick the check box, it goes to the reopen queue, where normal users (not moderators!) will review if it's suitable to reopen (also, if you want to address other users, you need to use @, otherwise they don't get notified). Adding unnecessary stuff will waste time of users, and you should not push to reopen your question when it has a suitable duplicate that answers your question.
